# Google APIs NodeJS Library OAuth2 Request

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to set up the authorization for Google API use in order to make requests to the Webmaster Tools API, but I can't seem to understand how to trigger the authentication. I have set up a route, that should trigger the authentication permissions calls when accessed, but I get a continual load signal with a no data received response. I'm using Google's library, https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/, and have my OAuth2 client ID credentials redirect uri pointing to `http://localhost:3000/` because I want to test the setup locally.

Here is my code:

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require('hbs');
var google = require('googleapis');
var webmastertools = google.webmasters('v3');





app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Handlebars View Engine
app.set('view engine', handlebars);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the public directory


app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server on port'+app.get('port'));
});

var routes = require('./app/routes');

app.use(routes);
```

Here is my route.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2('*client-id*', '*client-secret*', 'http://localhost:3000/');


router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index.hbs');
    });


router.get('/auth', function(req, res){
    //generater a url that asks permissions for Webmaster Tools
    var scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'
    ];

    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'online',
    scope: scopes   
    });

});

router.get('404', function(req, res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Not Found');
});


router.get('500', function(err,req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(500);
    res.send('500 - Server Error');
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should redirect to the authorization url provided by the generateAuthUrl. Something like:

```
router.get('/auth', function(req, res){
    //generater a url that asks permissions for Webmaster Tools
    var scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'
    ];

    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'online',
    scope: scopes   
    });
res.redirect(url);
});
```

This will take the user to the consent page where s/he can accpet the scopes and then be redirected to your redirect url. I don't have it in front of me but I think that's how I did it.